# how to retrieve complete data in java swing from text file using deserialization

Tags: java, swing

In my Swing Employee payroll project,employee details get added to file whenever i press save button..Each time i click on save,the details get populated on Jtable..here is my serialisation code.But when i try to retrieve complete data into Jtable,recently added detail is shown on Jtable. I am unable to retrieve complete data..

I dont know where am i going wrong..frnds need ur valuable suggestions.

```
  jsubmitbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

@Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {

 employeeInfo.setEmployeeId(Integer.parseInt(jId.getText()));
            employeeInfo.setName((String) jName.getText());
            employeeInfo.setSalary(Double.parseDouble(jSalary.getText()));
            employeeInfo.setHRA(Double.parseDouble(jHRA.getText()));
            employeeInfo.setMedical(Double.parseDouble(jMedical.getText()));
            employeeInfo.setPF(Double.parseDouble(jPF.getText()));
            employeeInfo.setPT(Double.parseDouble(jPT.getText()));
            employeeInfo.setNetSalary(Double.parseDouble(jNetSalary.getText()));
            employeeInfo.setGrossSalary(Double.parseDouble(jGrossSalary.getText()));
            Object Gender = jgenderbox.getSelectedItem();
            Object Dep = jdepartmentbox.getSelectedItem();
            Object DateOfJoining = dojspinner.getValue();
            Object DateOfBirth = dobspinner.getValue();
            employeeInfo.setHouse(new AddressDemo((String) jStreet.getText(),(String) jCity.getText(),Integer.parseInt(jPinCode.getText())));
            employeeInfo.setOffice(new AddressDemo( (String) jtextarea4.getText(), (String) jtextarea5.getText(),Integer.parseInt(jpincode.getText())));
            employeeInfo.setSkills((String) jSkills.getText());

            model21.addRow(new Object [] {employeeInfo.getEmployeeId()
                    ,employeeInfo.getName()
                    ,employeeInfo.getSalary()
                    ,employeeInfo.getHRA()
                    ,employeeInfo.getMedical()
                    ,employeeInfo.getPF()
                    ,employeeInfo.getPT()
                    ,employeeInfo.getNetSalary()
                    ,employeeInfo.getGrossSalary(),employeeInfo.getGender()
                    ,gender.valueOf((String)jgenderbox.getSelectedItem())
                    //,employeeInfo.getDep()
                    ,dep.valueOf((String)jdepartmentbox.getSelectedItem())
                    ,((Date)dojspinner.getValue())
                    ,((Date)dobspinner.getValue())
                    //,employeeInfo.getDateOfJoining()
                  //  ,employeeInfo.getDateOfBirth()
                    ,employeeInfo.getHouse()
                    ,employeeInfo.getOffice()
                    ,employeeInfo.getSkills()});try {

FileOutputStream fileOutputStream;
fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("D:\\employee1.txt");
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
objectOutputStream.writeObject(employeeInfo);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(EmployeeDemo.this,"Data is successfully inserted into database.");
objectOutputStream.close();
fileOutputStream.close();}catch (IOException{JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(EmployeeDemo.this,"Chutiyapa ho gaya!!");}


}   });
 jshow.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
 {
   @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

   EmployeeInfo employeeInfo = null;

        try 
{
        FileInputStream fileInputStream;
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("D:\\employee1.txt");
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
         employeeInfo = (EmployeeInfo)objectInputStream.readObject();
         objectInputStream.close();
            fileInputStream.close();

}

        catch (Exception e1)
        {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(EmployeeDemo.this,"Data not Entered!");         
        }
model21.addRow(new Object [] {employeeInfo.getEmployeeId()
        ,employeeInfo.getName()
        ,employeeInfo.getSalary()
        ,employeeInfo.getHRA()
        ,employeeInfo.getMedical()
        ,employeeInfo.getPF()
        ,employeeInfo.getPT()
        ,employeeInfo.getNetSalary()
        ,employeeInfo.getGrossSalary()
        ,gender.valueOf((String)jgenderbox.getSelectedItem())
        ,dep.valueOf((String)jdepartmentbox.getSelectedItem())
        ,((Date)dojspinner.getValue())
        ,((Date)dobspinner.getValue())
        ,employeeInfo.getHouse()
        ,employeeInfo.getOffice()
        ,employeeInfo.getSkills()});
        System.out.println("Done");
```

Comment: Impossible to tell from just this snippet. You are probably writing over the same object each time.  That is why you're only getting the last row.

Comment: how do i overcome my problem?wats the solution

Comment: Every time you save a new object, you'll have to save it to a new file. Or you serialize a list or array of the objects.  Your problem is probably with the serialization code, which you don't have posted.

Comment: i added my serialisation code...

Comment: Arraylist <employeeInfo> list = new Arraylist<employeeInfo>();               this is how i create array?

Comment: *"frnds need ur valuable suggestions."* I suggest you use a spell checker, and properly spell words like 'friends' and 'your'.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently writing over the previous object every time you add a new one.

When you call:

```
fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("D:\\employee1.txt")
```

You are writing over the old employee1.txt

You could overcome this by reading and writing an ArrayList object to the file.

Comment: Arraylist <employeeInfo> list = new Arraylist<employeeInfo>(); this is how i create array?

Comment: No offense meant by the link, but Google was able to find this simple example of creating a typed array list: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/use-array-lists-in-java.html